# Windows Server 2008 - change security settings for multiple files at once

Tags: windows-server-2008, ntfs

On Windows Server 2008, is there an easy way to modify security permissions for multiple files at once (as with Windows Server 2003)? Right-click - properties does not provide a "Security" tab if more than one file/directory is selected (i.e. ctrl-click multiple files).

As well, short of making registry changes, is there a way to edit files in notepad without having to open up notepad as an administrator? As it is, because of UAC you must open Notepad as an admin and then open the file you wish to edit (otherwise, cannot save).

UPDATE: Moved to https://serverfault.com/questions/30991/windows-server-2008-change-security-settings-for-multiple-files-at-once

ANSWER TO PART B: "As for editing the files: if you give regular (non-admin) users write permissions to the files, you don't have to run notepad as admin." Thanks @Martin v. Löwis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, there is cacls.exe (or xcacls) to change the ACLs for multiple files. Dunno whether you would call that "easy".

As for editing the files: if you give regular (non-admin) users write permissions to the files, you don't have to run notepad as admin.